# Can I compose gRPC proto definitions to multiple proto files?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a gRPC API definition like this (from Akka docs example), but much longer (4000 lines just the `service` part).

```proto
service GreeterService {
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}

    rpc ItKeepsTalking (stream HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}

    rpc ItKeepsReplying (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}

    rpc StreamHellos (stream HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}
}
```

However, the RPC list now grew too long and I want to "break it" into multiple files somehow, so the file is more readable. Something like this

```proto
// file 1:
service GreeterServicePartA {
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}

    rpc ItKeepsTalking (stream HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// file 2:
service GreeterServicePartB {
    rpc ItKeepsReplying (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}

    rpc StreamHellos (stream HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}
}

// main proto file:
import "file1"
import "file2"
service GreeterService = GreeterServicePartA + GreeterServicePartB
```

Even just defining the RPCs separately in different files and then writing something like this would help me:

```proto
service GreeterService {
    rpc SayHello = importedSayHello

    rpc ItKeepsTalking = importedKeepsTalking

    rpc ItKeepsReplying = importedKeepsReplying

    rpc StreamHellos = importedStreamHellos
}
```

Is it possible to somehow "compose" services in gRPC proto definitions like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't have a service that large. It sounds like a dumping ground of all methods if it has grown to be 4000 lines. I hope most of that is documentation... Normally I'd expect many more services based on subsets of the larger API. For example, let's say I have MyAndroidAppService, that can become a dumping ground. But I could have designed it as MyAndroidAppConfigService, MyAndroidAppNotificationService, MyAndroidAppChatService (assuming a very complex app with *lots* of methods).

But since you *already* have such a service, what can you do about it? You cannot split the `service` definition into multiple files. And if you split the service definition into multiple new services that will break gRPC's wire compatibility.

The most you can do is move the `message` definitions to a separate file and then use the normal [`import` mechanism](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing-definitions). Since moving messages to a different file can cause API incompatibilities in generated code, you can use `import public "path/to/messages.proto"` instead.

Comment: Hi Eric, whats the best way to define what should be its own service. If I'm at the planning stage of a basic CRUD style API, but I have several elements for example: Movies, Books, Audio. Would you define those three as the separate services? `service MovieService {Create, Get, List, Delete...etc}`. One more question, where do you define the relations between messages? Example, what if a Book had a movie adaption, is there a way to create relationships in messages but in separate services (files) ?

Comment: Yes, Movies, Books, Audio would be separate services. The relationship is easily just naming+documentation ("string book_id"). You can include some information inline by having a field to one of Book's messages, but references are generally just integer ids or strings. You might find https://cloud.google.com/apis/design useful which talks about making _REST_ APIs, which may or may not interest you. REST-style means you use URIs and namespacing for your IDs vs just bare integers and opaque strings.

Comment: appreciate the answer, very helpful!